# Grunt - Output file in same folder

Tags: gruntjs

I have the following gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  require('jit-grunt')(grunt);

  grunt.initConfig({
    uglify: {
      options: {
        manage: false
      },
      my_target: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'assets/js',
          src: '*.js',
          dest: 'assets/js/min' 
        }]
      },
    },
    less: {
      development: {
        options: {
          compress: true,
          yuicompress: true,
          optimization: 2
        },
        files: [
        {
          expand: true, // Recursive
          cwd: "assets", // The startup directory
          src: ["**/*.less"], // Source files
          dest: "assets/", // Destination
          ext: ".css" // File extension 
        }
      ]
      }
    },
    watch: {
      styles: {
        files: ['assets/**/*.less', 'assets/js/*.js'], // which files to watch
        tasks: ['less', 'newer:uglify'],
        options: {
          nospawn: true
        }
      }

    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-newer');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['less', 'watch', 'newer:uglify']);
};
```

And the following path distribution:

```
| assets
|-- folder-1
    |-- less
|-- folder-2
    |-- less
```

With the current `gruntfile.js`, my output is a sub-level of the less folder:

```
| assets
|-- folder-1
    |-- less
       |-- css
|-- folder-2
    |-- less
       |-- css
```

But it should be on the same level of the LESS file. For example:

```
| assets
|-- folder-1
    |-- less
    |-- css
|-- folder-2
    |-- less
    |-- css
```

Any idea on how to modify my `gruntfile.js`? Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your correctly, you want a css/ folder as a sibling of a less/ folder in each of your folder-{x}/ folders.

This can be done by adding the [rename](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#the-rename-property) property to your less task config:

```
files: [
    {
        expand: true, // Recursive
        cwd: "assets", // The startup directory
        src: ["**/*.less"], // Source files
        dest: "assets/", // Destination
        ext: ".css", // File extension
        rename: function (dest, src) {
            return (dest + src.replace('less/', 'css/'));
        }
    }
]
```